# Center Sub-Menu Under Parent Menu

Tags: wordpress

Project: lightertaste.com

Trying to center my submenu items under their parent menu item in my main navigation bar. The up-arrow before each, as well as the menu itself, should be completely centered on their parent menu text.

```css
/*
Site Navigation
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.genesis-nav-menu {
 clear: both;
 text-align: right;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
 display: inline-block;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px 10px;

 font-family: 'dosis-regular';
 color: #3d4646 !important;
 font-size: 21px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a:hover {
 color: #68a29c !important;
}

/* Sub Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.menu-primary li{
 position: relative;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu, 
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu {
 left: auto;

}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #3d4646;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
 z-index: 1000;
 left: -9999px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 150px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a {
 width: 150px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #3d4646;
 color: #ffffff !important;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: normal! important;
 text-align: center;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #68a29c;
 color: #3d4646 !important;
}
```

```html
<section id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu"><div class="widget-wrap"><nav class="nav-header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"><ul id="menu-main" class="menu genesis-nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-281" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-281"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Appetizers &#038; Snacks</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-297" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-297"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dips &#038; Spreads</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-389" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-389"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Meat &#038; Fish</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-390" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-390"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Fruits &#038; Vegetables</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-119"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breakfast</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-299"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Eggs &#038; Omelettes</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-298"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pancakes &#038; Waffles</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-260" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-260"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Oatmeal &#038; Granola</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-259"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breads, Muffins, &#038; Pastries</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-261" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-261"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Shakes &#038; Smoothies</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-120"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Lunch</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-258"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sandwiches &#038; Wraps</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-262" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-262"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Salads &#038; Power Bowls</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-263"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Soups &#038; Stews</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-121"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dinner</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-279" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-279"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Quick &#038; Easy</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-278"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Beef &#038; Pork</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-276" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-276"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Chicken &#038; Poultry</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-277"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Seafood &#038; Shellfish</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-273" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-273"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Casseroles &#038; One-Pans</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-274" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-274"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pastas &#038; Risottos</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-275"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pizzas &#038; Flatbreads</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-124"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Desserts</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-264"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Cakes &#038; Pies</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Cookies &#038; Brownies</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-288" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-288"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Ice Creams &#038; Sorbets</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-123"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sides</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-392" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-392"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Vegetables &#038; Potatoes</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-391" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-391"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Rice &#038; Noodles</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breads &#038; Rolls</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></nav></div></section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for you..
Try it..

Just copy and past it..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            /*
            Site Navigation
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

            .genesis-nav-menu {
                clear: both;
                text-align: right;
            }

            .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
                display: inline-block;position:relative;
            }

            .genesis-nav-menu a {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                padding: 0px 10px;

                font-family: 'dosis-regular';
                color: #3d4646 !important;
                font-size: 21px;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                font-weight: 500;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: lowercase;
            }

            .genesis-nav-menu a:hover {
                color: #68a29c !important;
            }

            /* Sub Navigation
            --------------------------------------------- */

            .menu-primary li{
                position: relative;
                display:block;
            }

            .genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu:before {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-left: 10px solid transparent;
                border-right: 10px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 10px solid #3d4646;
            }

            .genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
                z-index: 1000;padding:0;
                display: none;
                position: absolute;top:100%;
                min-width: 150px;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,0);
            }
            .genesis-nav-menu li:hover>.sub-menu {display:block;}
            .genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu li{display:block;}
            .genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a {
                display:block;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #3d4646;
                color: #ffffff !important;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: normal! important;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
                background-color: #68a29c;
                color: #3d4646 !important;
            }
            .widget{max-width:1200px;padding:0 15px;margin:0 auto;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu"><div class="widget-wrap"><nav class="nav-header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"><ul id="menu-main" class="menu genesis-nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-281" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-281"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Appetizers &#038; Snacks</span></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-297" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-297"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dips &#038; Spreads</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-389" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-389"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Meat &#038; Fish</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-390" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-390"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Fruits &#038; Vegetables</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-119"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breakfast</span></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-299"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Eggs &#038; Omelettes</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-298"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pancakes &#038; Waffles</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-260" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-260"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Oatmeal &#038; Granola</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-259"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breads, Muffins, &#038; Pastries</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-261" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-261"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Shakes &#038; Smoothies</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-120"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Lunch</span></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-258"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sandwiches &#038; Wraps</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-262" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-262"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Salads &#038; Power Bowls</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-263"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Soups &#038; Stews</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-121"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dinner</span></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-279" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-279"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Quick &#038; Easy</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-278"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Beef &#038; Pork</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-276" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-276"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Chicken &#038; Poultry</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-277"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Seafood &#038; Shellfish</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-273" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-273"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Casseroles &#038; One-Pans</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-274" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-274"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pastas &#038; Risottos</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-275"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pizzas &#038; Flatbreads</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-124"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Desserts</span></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-264"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Cakes &#038; Pies</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Cookies &#038; Brownies</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-288" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-288"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Ice Creams &#038; Sorbets</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-123"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sides</span></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-392" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-392"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Vegetables &#038; Potatoes</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-391" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-391"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Rice &#038; Noodles</span></a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breads &#038; Rolls</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul></nav></div></section>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I omitted the coding listed below and made no changes to the HTML but it's working now. Thank you!!

.widget{max-width:1200px;padding:0 15px;margin:0 auto;}

Answer (score 0):

That's how I'd do it:

```css
/*
Site Navigation
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.genesis-nav-menu {
 clear: both;
 text-align: right;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
 display: inline-block;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px 10px;

 font-family: 'dosis-regular';
 color: #3d4646 !important;
 font-size: 21px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: lowercase;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a:hover {
 color: #68a29c !important;
}

/* Sub Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.menu-primary li{
 position: relative;
}

#menu-main > .menu-item {
  position:relative;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu, 
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu {
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #3d4646;
  margin-left:-10px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
 z-index: 1000;
 left: -9999px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 150px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a {
 width: 150px;
  margin-left:-85px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #3d4646;
 color: #ffffff !important;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: normal! important;
 text-align: center;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #68a29c;
 color: #3d4646 !important;
}
```

```html
<section id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu"><div class="widget-wrap"><nav class="nav-header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"><ul id="menu-main" class="menu genesis-nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-281" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-281"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Appetizers &#038; Snacks</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-297" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-297"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dips &#038; Spreads</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-389" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-389"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Meat &#038; Fish</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-390" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-390"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Fruits &#038; Vegetables</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-119"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breakfast</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-299" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-299"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Eggs &#038; Omelettes</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-298"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pancakes &#038; Waffles</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-260" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-260"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Oatmeal &#038; Granola</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-259"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breads, Muffins, &#038; Pastries</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-261" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-261"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Shakes &#038; Smoothies</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-120"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Lunch</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-258"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sandwiches &#038; Wraps</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-262" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-262"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Salads &#038; Power Bowls</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-263"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Soups &#038; Stews</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-121"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dinner</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-279" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-279"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Quick &#038; Easy</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-278"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Beef &#038; Pork</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-276" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-276"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Chicken &#038; Poultry</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-277"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Seafood &#038; Shellfish</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-273" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-273"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Casseroles &#038; One-Pans</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-274" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-274"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pastas &#038; Risottos</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-275"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Pizzas &#038; Flatbreads</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-124"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Desserts</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-264"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Cakes &#038; Pies</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Cookies &#038; Brownies</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-288" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-288"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Ice Creams &#038; Sorbets</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-123"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sides</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-392" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-392"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Vegetables &#038; Potatoes</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-391" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-391"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Rice &#038; Noodles</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breads &#038; Rolls</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></nav></div></section>
```